# MS Excel loads excelsheet with worksheet tabs hidden

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I am using MS Excel 2016. When I open an excel sheet, the worksheet tabs are hidden. To get them to appear, I have to click on the maximize window icon at the upper right corner. How can I get Excel to start in "Maximize window mode" all the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for any program:
Right-click the icon you use to start Excel (in the task bar, or on the desktop, or whereever) and chose properties. There is a setting which allows to chose to open 'minimized',''in a window', or 'maximized'. The default is 'in a window', just change it to 'maximized'.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, when you open the workbook, part of it is off the screen. If that is the case, resize it so it fits entirely on the desktop, then close Excel without saving. The next time you open a new workbook, it should be sized correctly. (If it is an old workbook, then resize it and save it).